# Office 365 E1 Vs Microsoft 365 Apps for Business

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, licensing

Inside our Office 365 tenant , we have 2 types of licenses for our users (Office 365 E1 & Microsoft 365 Apps for Business), as follow:-

[image]

But we are not able to find any differences between the 2 licenses. so can anyone advice on the main differences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two licenses, refer to:

[image]

More information:

https://www.agileit.com/news/office-365-license-comparison/

Comment: but does Microsoft 365 Apps for Business gives you SharePoint online , OneDrive and Yammer? as based on our case it will allow our users to login to SharePoint,Yammer and OneDrive, but based on the picture you provided it will not,, so i am confused..

Comment: Please refer to this post:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/445666/can-a-user-with-microsoft-365-apps-for-business-lo.html?childToView=446634#answer-446634